# Start Glassfish domain and memory allocating (in VPS)

Tags: jvm, glassfish, vps

I got a VPS and unzipped GlassfishV3 Open source edition, my VPS has 650MB RAM, when I try to :

sh asadmin start-domain

I got a Memory allocation error=12 , I change the -Xmx512m to -Xmx128 in my domain1 config file but the problem still exist!

free -m:

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
1024        276        747
```

in addition, I can run java -Xmx512m -version successfully

What is the issue?

RGDS

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

asadmin start-domain -v

If catastrophic errors are logged (or just printed to stdout/stderr) BEFORE the Logging Service starts in GlassFish you will never see the output.

With this command you will see all such output.